# I want to change the class of my div on text change using vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

ps below is my code,

```
<div v-if="data" :id="'note'+data.id" contentEditable="false"  v-on:dblclick="dblclick(data.id)" v-text="notes" data-text="  ההערות" class="transparent"  @blur="dblclick(data.id)"></div>

<script>
import {AlertBus} from "../app";

export default {
    name: "NotesComponent",
    props: {
       data: {},
        name: {},
        submit: {},
        dblclick: {},
        meta: {},
        classes: {},
    },
    data() {
        return {
            notes: this.data.note,
            pageUrl: window.pageUrl,
        }

    },
    methods: {
    }
}
```

in the code above i want the div class to change once the text changes, code fetches content from my database and i have a default text for div and i want to change the class once the text in the div changes

Comment: Hello Dear Can you explain well what you want to do !

Comment: ok @Birante, i have this div which have a default text with a transparent class, but i want the class to change once i change the text of the div to something else also the class that it changes to should be retained even when i refresh the page

Comment: How does the text of the div change?

Comment: on double click, the text changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets making simple.

According to the vuejs documentation this is how you can use class.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      data: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    changeBackground() {
      return this.data.length > 0 ? "bg-one" : "bg-two";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.bg-one {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-two {
  background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div :class="changeBackground">
      <input v-model="data" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Look at this sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-star-ronjr